# mailing list auto approval subscription

Tags: list

Hello community and thanks you for reading this

I need for a client who run his website under expressionengine to modify the core to auto approve a user when he subscribe to the newsletter (mailing list plugin)

Basicly I want to keep the automatic email send by the system (i will modify the content and erase the link to confirm the subscription) and have a auto approve subscription. No need for the user to click to approve his subscription

Many thanks to someone who find the solution.

Comment: Are you talking about subscribing to a newsletter, or confirming the user's email address?

Comment: thank for the reply Adrian, i talk about the email send fo confirming the user's email address. i want to keep this automatic email on (to give important informations) but take off the manual confirmation link of user's email address and automaticly approve the user. sorry about my bad english ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're not going about this quite the right way. What I would suggest is that you remove the email confirmation step (set member accounts to register straight away). That way you don't need to worry about hacking EE internals to change the member registration process.

Next problem you want to solve is sending a "welcome" email. I would take a look at [Postmaster](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/postmaster) to see whether that will meet your needs. But treat the "send welcome email on member signup" separately from whether or not member email addresses require confirmation.

Comment: Hello Adrian, thanks you very much for your answers and for the plugin, i will ask my client if he want to pay for it.

For your first solution, you talk about member accounts registration but it's not the same process for the mailing list registration. if i turn off the email confirmation in the member options it will not turn off on the mailing list (my client don't need member registration, just people to be register on mailing list)

Comment: Ok, so you are talking about subscribing to a newsletter (mailing list), not confirming a (registered) member's email address. That's what I asked you before. For the record, most spam laws require the user to confirm their email address (and apart from the law, it's the polite thing to do), so you probably don't want to remove the email confirmation.

Comment: sorry my fault i misunderstood! yes i know but it s the wish of my client that's why i ask this sort of question ;-) i will tru to explain to him why it's not possible. Apart from all theses considerations, for my technical knowledge only, how can i do it? thanks Adrian

Answer (score 0):

Open system/expressionengine/modules/mailinglist/mod.mailinglist.php

then set

```
var $email_confirm = FALSE;
```